# Move triggers to copy of spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

How to move triggers from spreadsheet to its copy?

In some spreadsheet there are some triggers: onOpen, onEdit. While I make a copy of that spreadsheet triggers aren't transfered to it from original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a copy of a Google Spreadsheet, all the associated code (Google Script) is copied to the new sheet. However, you would need to authorize the script again and install the triggers manually since the new sheet is technically a new Google Cloud project and requires authorization.